# Binding ConverterParameter={Binding ...}

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно в качестве параметра для конвертера указать `Binding`, но это невозможно, так как `ConverterParameter` не является `DependencyProperty`.

Все решения, которые я нашел в сети, подразумевали использование `MultiBinding` и это работало. Пока мне не потребовалась обратная конвертация. Подскажите как быть.

**UPD**

Пришлось много чего писать в комментариях, перенесу это сюда на всякий случай.

Конвертер принимает V (Value) P (Parameter) а на выходе ждет R (Result)

Обратная конвертация устроена так же.

Если я использую MultiBinding, то конвертер будет принимать V[] (Values) и на выходе ожидать R (Result)

Обратная конвертация будет принимать V (Value) а на выходе ждать R[] (Results)

Но у меня на самом деле есть 3 переменные (a,b,c). a = b * c

То есть для вычисления любой из этих переменных мне нужны две другие. А в случае с мультибиндингом мне предлагает в обратной конвертации восстановить b и с из a

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59778/discussion-on-question-by-irumba-binding-converterparameterbinding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConverterParameter` не является `DependencyProperty`, и не подхватывает изменения. Таким образом, простое использование `ConverterParameter`.

Необходимо использовать более честный подход. Заведите отдельный класс, который будет заниматься отображением точек модели в пиксельные координаты. Экземпляр этого класса и можно передавать в качестве параметра в конвертер.

(*реальный пример кода приведу позже*)

Comment: эмм... я же сказал, что мне не подходит MultiBinding из-за проблем с обратной конвертацией

Comment: @iRumba: Окей, тогда расскажите **в подробностях** о вашей задаче.

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу описал задачу. В самом вопросе только абстрактные данные, но я считаю их должно хватить

Comment: @iRumba: Нет, нужны конкретные данные по задаче и смысл ваших переменных. Абстрактная задача не решается, так что скорее всего вы пошли неправильным путём. Опишите вашу конкретную проблему.

Comment: @iRumba: Ага, вижу, координаты и масштаб. Понял. У меня была такая проблема, решал по-другому. Вернусь с обеда, опишу работающее и правильное с моей точки зрения решение.

Comment: Вот тут накладочка выходит. У меня модель не имеет координаты. Это потому, что логика работы от координат не зависит. Это очень странно, я понимаю, но это так :)

Comment: @iRumba: А что есть? Давайте конкретную информацию, без неё я не смогу угадать, что вам нужно.

Comment: Модель имеет некоторые величины, которые нужны для расчета. Но к карте они отношения не имеют. Карта тут только для наглядности. Суть в том, что я свое прозрачное окошко накладываю поверх реальной карты в стороннем приложении, объекты располагаю так, как вижу их на той карте, потому что реальных координат у меня даже и нет. Далее задаю величины (которые, как я сказал, не имеют отношение к координатам) и получаю некоторое визуальное решение задачи, для которой и создаю приложение. **То есть координаты мне нужны только для визуализации, не более того**

Comment: Ах да, тут же сразу возникает вопрос, а зачем вообще нужен масштаб карты и реальные координаты. Дело в том, что среди величин модели есть некий радиус, который не только участвует в расчетах, но и по нему визуально удобно располагать объекты в моей программе над объектами в стороннем приложении.

Comment: @iRumba: Тогда давайте возвратимся к началу. Какие у вас есть величины, и какой у них **точный** смысл?